# Advice for preparing a virtual presentation

Tags: conference, presentation, audio-video-recording

I have a paper that has been accepted for a conference abroad, but because I have been put on administrative duties on my university I will not be able to make the presentation. So, I have spoken with the PC of the conference and has given me the option to make a presentation and send it to him to present it in the conference allotted time. For me is the first time that I will be doing this, so I would like to know some advice on how to do this presentation:

For example, should I make a simple Powerpoint and just recording my voice? or should I make a presentation like those that are on the MOOCs courses? As silly as it sounds I have no clue on how to prepare a presentation in this format.

Any advice?

Comment: If I were in your situation, I would check with my college's video support office, to find out what can be done and how much work it would involve.  They did a great job for me, when I was too sick to travel to campus but able to teach my class from home by video-conference plus slides  (I wouldn't even try to combine power point and voice recording on my own, but perhaps you're more competent in that area.)

Comment: Andreas is on the right track. There are a large variety of video services available these days. Most laptops have a webcam pre-installed, though the quality of such cameras is often not the greatest. It is certainly possible to give a presentation over the internet. Your image can be on a big-screen TV, and you can see the audience in return. You can even take interactive questions. A variety of service providers allow such video for low cost, or even no cost. Though, in some cases, you should be aware that there may be people other than your intended audience watching.

Comment: By the way, whatever the reasons for you being "put on administrative leave" you should probably inform the conference of sufficient details for them to make an informed decisions about your participation. Not saying you need to tell them every detail, just enough that they won't feel misled.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to know the specific requirements from the conference host. **Do they have a specific file format that they want you to use?** Otherwise, you might want to do a screencast recording. T**here are free software available such OBS (Open Broadcaster Software)** where you can record your screen and microphone at the same time. That way, you can go through your powerpoint presentation while recording both the screen and audio. Make sure you use a good microphone when recording and try to minimize as much background noise as possible.

Good luck with your presentation, I'm sure you'll nail it!

PS: Let me know if you're struggling with getting OBS to work, it's fairly easy and straightforward so there shouldn't be any issues (also many guides available on youtube).